# How to store user input in a 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, user-interface

So I have this GUI application that is supposed to calculate shipping costs. First I need to enter the number of packages that is being shipped (already done), then choose package # from a domainUpDown tool(also complete), and then input dimensions for selected package in a text box. This is where I'm stuck. This is what I have thus far.

```
    const int WEIGHT = 0
    const int NMBR_OF_PROPETIES = 7;
    const int MAX_PACKAGES = 10;
    const double FLAT_RATE = 4.99;
    int numOfPackages, packageNumber;


    double[,] packagesArray = new double[MAX_PACKAGES, NMBR_OF_PROPETIES];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //label texts get initialized
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(numOfPackagesTextBox.Text, out numOfPackages))
        {
            //message box tells that number cant be parsed
        }
        else if(numOfPackages > 0 && numOfPackages < 10)
        {
            //everything in the program is enabled       
        }
        else
        {
            //message box saying that you can't ship more than 10 packages
        }

        //adding package numbers to the domainUpDown tool
        DomainUpDown.DomainUpDownItemCollection items = packageUpDown.Items;
        for (int packageNumber = 1; packageNumber <= numOfPackages; packageNumber++)
        {
            items.Add(packageNumber);
        }

    }

    private void weightBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        packagesArray[(int)packageUpDown.SelectedItem, WEIGHT] = Convert.ToInt32(weightBox.Text); 
        //also here goes the rest of the dimension entry
    }//from here i don't know what to do, and im sure that this isn't right..
```

The thing I'm confused about is how to save entered text if user somehow changes package number from domainUpDown tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried registering to the [OnChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.domainupdown.onchanged.aspx) or [SelectedItemChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.domainupdown.selecteditemchanged.aspx) events of the DomainUpDown ?

Perform saving on the OnChanged event handler.

Example:

```
     myDomainUpDown.OnChanged += new EventHandler(myDomainUpDown_OnChanged);

     void OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
          //save all the information you need in whatever collection/file/db you want 
      }
```